# De-aggregate data: statistically correct approaches?

Tags: distributions, classification, statistical-significance, aggregation, disaggregation

> Reading some research studies and there are interesting aggregated results. I want to plug it into a neural network (or similar) in order to categorise individual entries into alignment with what the aggregates say.

Given a single metric—say: age range within $20$ – $30$—an aggregated average; a sample size $n$; could I just just generate a random distribution within that range and spread them across $n$ rows, ensuring the average stays the same? - And will this work for multiple metrics?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's the relation between your quoted section up top and the section below?

Comment: Categorise new data into where it would appear in the aggregated data, including incomplete new data (see [my other question](http://ai.stackexchange.com/q/2792)).

Comment: I'm extremely confused as to what you're trying to do or what you're asking. I don't understand, "Categorise new data into where it would appear in the aggregated data, including incomplete new data" at all...

Comment: So I read a study that only has aggregate data, like "of 500 people surveyed who had red hair within 20-30 age-range, only 30% bought a blue hat; however 60% of red-heads bought a blue hat within the 30-50 age range". Now given a new individual, and expanding the aggregated data to include 10+ metrics, I'm looking to output the likelihood this individual bought a blue hat.